# React Native not working after Xcode 10 update

Tags: javascript, react-native

I just upgraded to Xcode 10 and now after attempting to run my existing projects I was met with the below error. After searching I found the following issue when running react native init https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/21490. This solution also fixes my issue.

However I am wondering if anyone knows why my current project now require me to run the bundler as a separate instance. It's not the end of the world but it's certainly not the best experience.

Does anyone know of a way the get everything working as it was before without the need to run the following commands:

1. rm -rf $TMPDIR/react-*; rm -rf $TMPDIR/haste-*; rm -rf
   $TMPDIR/metro-*; watchman watch-del-all
2. react-native start  --reset-cache
3. (separate terminal) react-native run-ios

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I had issues with the build after Xcode update, what I did to fix it is switch the Build System to `Legacy Build System`

From File > Workspace Settings

[image]

Or by pressing on the hammer icon on the right of the status bar

Change the build system to `Legacy Build System`

[image]

Also make sure that you still have the bundle script in Build Phases

[image]

Tell me know if that works with you

Comment: I verified the bundle script in the second image you posted. Im not sure where to find the hammer icon in your first image.

Comment: `File > Workspace Settings`, I also edited my answer

Comment: Thanks but this change didn't work for me. I get the same error.

Comment: Try to update watchman with `brew upgrade watchman` and try this https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/14118#issuecomment-334009689

Comment: Worked for me! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You may need to add an additional Build Phase to the xCode project after "Bundle React Native code and images"

Add a new build script by selecting the + sign on the top left and selecting "New Run Script Phase" then add the following

```
if nc -w 5 -z localhost 8081 ; then
if ! curl -s "http://localhost:8081/status" | grep -q "packager- 
status:running" ; then
echo "Port 8081 already in use, packager is either not running or not 
running correctly"
exit 2

fi
else
open "$SRCROOT/../node_modules/react- 
native/scripts/launchPackager.command" || echo "Can't start packager 
automatically"
fi
```